# How to show stacktrace for gnome-shell extensions in Gnome Shell 3.16.2?

Tags: debian, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

Today, I upgraded from Debian Jessie (stable) to Stretch (testing), and many extensions I need to work are no longer marked as compatible.
I'm quite sure it's no big deal for most of them (maybe just `manifest.json` to update).

But my problem is that I can't find a way of having **js tracebacks** to identify loading problems.
Before, there was logs in console when executing `gnome-shell --replace` command, or simply in **`~/.xsession-errors`** file.
As far as I can see, **`~/.xsession-errors`** file seems not logging anything from js. To test, I used [looking glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass) and tried to log something.

I had a look on [Debian changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/g/gnome-shell-extensions/gnome-shell-extensions_3.16.2-1_changelog), but didn't helped.

Are the logs gone to another file ?
Is where a simple way of debugging js without [using gdb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Debugging) ?

Any help would be really appreciated !
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25068964/3548266

The reason `.xsession-errors` doest not exist is that Debian testing now uses `systemd`. Use `journalctl` command to display the logs related to `gnome-session` like that:

```
journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-session -f -o cat
```

While it is running, unload/reload the extension that doesn't work or restart gnome-shell (alt-f2 r enter) then read the exceptions and/or errors.

To load/unload the extension from the command line:

`ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
gnome-shell-extension-tool --enable-extension <name@domain>
gnome-shell-extension-tool --disable-extension <name@domain>`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: after checking, I see the logs with `tail -f /var/log/messages` too

Comment: Thanks.

When I reload Gnome with an extension in error state (which shloud output a stacktrace in logs somewhere), nothing is added in journalctl (in root).

When I try in "looging glasses" `global.log("foo")` => nothing. Nothing in /var/log/messages too.

Comment: you can do `ls -lt /var/log` to see which log was written last after doing `global.log`

Comment: Note: You cannot simply restart gnome-shell under Wayland, you have to log out and in. On Ubuntu 22.04 you can use `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell -f` or `journalctl /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary -f` depending on what you're looking for.