# How do I log from an Extension?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm writing new Extension code and want to log to a file for debugging purposes.

I've tried using the print() function to write to ~/.cache/gdm/session.log as explained here: http://codeisland.org/2013/making-gnome-shell-extensions/

This does not work. Does print() write elsewhere? Also, I see that other extensions use log(). Where can I view the output of that?

Is any of this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

You can find an answer in this topic : [How to test / debug GNOME Shell extensions? Is there any tool for that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425616/how-to-test-debug-gnome-shell-extensions-is-there-any-tool-for-that)

Some features are outdated, but you can use in a terminal :

```
gnome-shell --replace &
```

or

```
journalctl -f
```

Every log(blabla); in your extension will be printed in the terminal.